# Animating UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift, uipopovercontroller

Does anyone know how to change the default 'present' animation of a `UIPopoverController`? By default it's alpha-fading in and I would rather want to scroll it into the center of the screen coming from the bottom? I think that's very common actually but I can't find any detailed info about how to animate it. I doubt I will need animation blocks for this? Likewise, on closing I want it to scroll-animate back into the bottom.

I'm using a custom method in a `UIPopoverController` sub class that I'm using...

```
public func present(size:CGSize, position:CGRect, view:UIView!, animated:Bool = true)
{
    setPopoverContentSize(size, animated: false);
    presentPopoverFromRect(position, inView: view, permittedArrowDirections: nil, animated: animated);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can present it from any direction or from any point of the screen.

```
  UIPopoverController* popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];        
  [popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.txtTemp.bounds inView:self.txtTemp permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Do you want remove only fading effects or animations, there is an example 
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/crproducttour help to you.